# Closing a Tab from a Safari App Extension

Tags: safari, tabs, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am having a surprisingly hard time finding a way to close a tab from a Safari App Extension.

I can open a tab with

```
SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow(completionHandler: { 
    $0?.openTab(with: url, makeActiveIfPossible: true) 
})
```

Yet neither the returned SFSafariTab, nor the SFSafariWindow have `close()` (or `performClose()`).

I can send a friendly message to the JS side of the extension and run `window.close();`, but this is limited to tabs that were also created via Javascript. Any tabs opened by the user, or `target="_blank"` are blocked off.

The third option seems to be the deprecated Safari JS Extension API. I have not yet succeeded in making this work, and it feels icky to invest time into  such a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now in safari 12.1 have facility to close current tab.

```
/// Closes this tab. If this is the last tab in its window, the window is also closed.
- (void)close SF_AVAILABLE_MAC_SAFARI(12_1);
```